# Local speed of sound in a perfect gas

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, acoustics, ideal-gas, speed

I have some doubts regarding the derivation of the formula for the local speed of sound in a perfect gas. I am going to use the [related wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound) as a blueprint to expose my doubts.

We can show that the value of the local speed of sound $c$ is:

$$c = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right)_S} \tag{1}$$

**My first problem** regards this subscript $S$: this means of course that we are taking the derivative assuming that entropy is constant<sup>1</sup>, the process is *isoentropic*, **does this mean that the process is also adiabatic?** I think that the answer to this must be yes, my reasoning is quite simple: since we know, from the second law of thermodynamics, that:
$$dQ=TdS$$
$dS=0$ must mean that $dQ=0$. Is my reasoning correct? But since, going forward, we mostly care about the fact that the process is adiabatic, why don't we simply write:

$$c = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right)_Q}$$

am I missing something?

**My second problem is:** I would prefer to write the local speed of sound **explicitly** and in terms of the **temperature** $T$ of the gas, the *Boltzmann's constant* and the **mass of the particle** of the perfect gas.<sup>2</sup> I know that this is possible in some way. To achive this re-writing of (1) I was thinking of using the two main information about our system: the fact that we are dealing with a **perfect gas**, and the fact that the process is **adiabatic**; so seems a good idea to use:
$$PV=nRT \tag{2}$$
the *equation of state of the perfect gas* and
$$P=K\rho ^\gamma \tag{3}$$
the *pressure equation for an adiabatic transformation*, where $\gamma$ is the ratio of the specific heats and $K$ si some unknown constant, if I understand correctly.
But if I try to apply (3) to (1) I get:

$$c=\sqrt{K\gamma \rho ^{\gamma -1}}$$

**and then I am stuck!** I don't know how to proceed. In some lecture notes I have found it is written that applying (3) to (1) **should lead to:**

$$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right)_S=\gamma \frac{P_0}{\rho _0} \tag{4}$$
where $P_0$ and $\rho _0$ are some initial values for $P$ and $\rho$, and the ratio I think is supposed to be constant, but I don't get why.

**Anyway:** I don't know how to get from (1) to the end result, that according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound#Details) should be:

$$c=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma k_B T}{m}} \tag{5}$$

where $m$ is the mass of a single perfect gas molecule.

**TL;DR: How can I get (5) from (1)?**

---

[1]: This is reasonable since, if I understand correctly, the pressure wave travels fast enough to assume that no relevant exchange of heat can occur.

[2]: Essentially I want to write $c$ in terms of the mean thermal energy $k_BT$, or if you prefer in terms of the thermal kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems come down to algebra. In your equation after (3), multiply and divide by $\rho$ (under the square root), combine the $\rho$ in numerator, then substitute P for $K\rho^\gamma$.  That gives $\gamma P/\rho$.

Ideal gas law is $P=\rho R_g T$ where $R_g$ is the gas constant for the gas, e.g., R=8.314 J/K mol, 1 mole of air is about .o29 kg, so $R_g=8.314/.029 = 287. J/kg K$.

Therefore,

$ c= \sqrt{\gamma R_g T}$

I'll leave it to you to relate Boltzman constant and $R$ (universal gas constant) and $R_g$.

Comment: Really clever trick that I missed. Thank you. But you have made a mistake into one of your formulas. I have edited your answer so it should be fine now.